# Can I select an element and change Classname like this?

Tags: javascript, class, selector, classname, queryselector

```js
function name() {
    const select = document.querySelector("#id");
    select.classname = ("customclass")
}
```

**I've written this code. But I'm unable to change the Classname.**

Comment: you'll want to use `select.classList.add('customClass')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property:

```js
const select = document. querySelector("#id"); 
select.className = "customclass";
console.log(select);
```

```html
<div id="id"></div>
```

Another way would be adding it to the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) as suggested in the comments:

```js
const select = document. querySelector("#id"); 
select.classList.add("customclass");
console.log(select);
```

```html
<div id="id"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks man... I can't even see the tiny mistake 

Comment: The difference between the two being that setting `className` overwrites all existing classes, while `classList` allows you to manage the list of assigned classes with `add()` `remove()` and `toggle()` methods.